# change strokeDashoffset with Percent when using circle and svg

Tags: html, css, svg

i want to create a circle progressbar .

i write this code in html :

```
    <svg>
        <circle cx="70" cy="70" id="progress" r="70"></circle>
        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
      </svg>
```

and write this code in css :

```
 svg {
  width: 155px;
  margin-top: -131px;
  transform: translateX(16px);
  > circle {
    width: 136px;
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 10px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
    stroke-dasharray: 440;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: translateX(8px);
  }
 }
```

but when i pass the percent for change withc `strokeDashoffset` it not worked :

```
calc(400- (400 * 87) / 100)
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: if you want to use calc, you must use units. Which of calc(400- (400 * 87) / 100) is a percentage? Where's the % sign?

Comment: @RobertLongson where i must using the % ???

Comment: Well what value in your calc expression do you think should be a percentage?

Comment: @RobertLongson i want when file is uploaded and precent is changed the circule is complete

Comment: What percent? Other than the title there's no percent in your question and no % sign in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `calc()` function is a bit picky and doesn't work in all situations. You can use unitless `calc()` in some cases.

For example it would work with `line-height` but not for `strokedashoffset`. I don't know why and if there's a rule to this. Anyone?

Then as a general rule you need space around your operand, so here you have a space missing before your minus sign.

And last but not least your strokedasharray value seems too big compare to the size of the circle to be able to see any dash.